# Is there a way to obtain coefficients for each step of the optimization algorithm in glm function?

Tags: r, glm

When one performs a logit regression in R, it is possible to obtain coefficients after the optimization algorithm has converged (or not) with `coefficients()` function:

```
library(MASS)
data(menarche)
glm.out = glm(cbind(Menarche, Total-Menarche) ~ Age,
               family=binomial(logit), data=menarche)
coefficients(glm.out)
## (Intercept)         Age 
## -21.226395    1.631968
```

Is there a way to obtain coefficients for each step of the optimization algorithm to trace its steps?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The internals of glm.fit have changed (see comment from @John) so use this instead. It does not rely on line positions of the internals but rather intercepts each instance of cat in glm.fit and adds a message to iteration message so although it still depends on the internals it should be a bit less fragile.  This worked for me in R 4.1 and 4.2.

```
library(MASS)
data(menarche)

trace(glm.fit, quote(cat <- function(...) {
  base::cat(...)
  if (...length() >= 3 && identical(..3, " Iterations - ")) print(coefold)
}))
glm.out = glm(cbind(Menarche, Total-Menarche) ~ Age,
                     family=binomial(logit), data=menarche,
                     control = glm.control(trace = TRUE))
untrace(glm.fit)
```

---

**Previous solution**

The `control=` argument with the value shown causes the deviance to print and the `trace` statement will cause the coefficient values to print:

```
trace(glm.fit, quote(print(coefold)), at = list(c(22, 4, 8, 4, 19, 3)))
glm.out = glm(cbind(Menarche, Total-Menarche) ~ Age,
                     family=binomial(logit), data=menarche,
                     control = glm.control(trace = TRUE))
```

The output will look like this:

```
Tracing glm.fit(x = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  .... step 22,4,8,4,19,3 
NULL
Deviance = 27.23412 Iterations - 1
Tracing glm.fit(x = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  .... step 22,4,8,4,19,3 
[1] -20.673652   1.589536
Deviance = 26.7041 Iterations - 2
Tracing glm.fit(x = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  .... step 22,4,8,4,19,3 
[1] -21.206854   1.630468
Deviance = 26.70345 Iterations - 3
Tracing glm.fit(x = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  .... step 22,4,8,4,19,3 
[1] -21.226370   1.631966
Deviance = 26.70345 Iterations - 4
```

To remove the trace use:

```
untrace(glm.fit)
```

Note that in the `trace` call, `coefold` is the name of a variable used internally in `glm.fit` source code and the numbers used refer to statement numbers in the source code and so either could need to be changed if `glm.fit` source changes. I am using "R version 3.2.2 Patched (2015-10-19 r69550)".

Comment: "either could need to be changed if `glm.fit` source changes": I think this may have happened in 4.1 or so as this command has started to return an error.

Comment: Have fixed this.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you. Would upvote again if I could.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend performing a by-hand approach. Modify argument to `glm.control` and supply the fitted values within a `while` loop. See as follows:

```
library(MASS)
data(menarche)
converged <- F
coeftrace <- matrix(0, 25, 2)
i <- 1
mu <- NULL

while(!converged & i <= 25) {
  glm.out = glm(cbind(Menarche, Total-Menarche) ~ Age,
                mustart = mu,
                family=binomial(logit), data=menarche, 
                control=glm.control(maxit=1))
  mu <- glm.out$fitted.values
  coeftrace[i,] <- coef(glm.out)
  i <- i+1
  converged<- glm.out$converged
}
coefficients(glm.out)
```

Gives:

```
> coeftrace
           [,1]     [,2]
 [1,] -20.67365 1.589536
 [2,] -21.20685 1.630468
 [3,] -21.22637 1.631966
 [4,] -21.22639 1.631968
 [5,]   0.00000 0.000000
 [6,]   0.00000 0.000000
 [7,]   0.00000 0.000000
 [8,]   0.00000 0.000000
```

The benefit is these values can be used for analysis, such as plotting. Note, the initial conditions supplied by `glm` is not captured in this answer or in @GGrothendieck's answer either. That is, the `glm.fit` behavior is to use `binomial()$initialize` within the `glm.fit` environment to set initial conditions, and would correspond to coefficients. This approach is more efficient than supplying wild starting parameters. If I change `mu` above, I may add 4 additional iterations.

```
library(MASS)
data(menarche)
converged <- F
coeftrace <- matrix(0, 25, 2)
i <- 1
mu <- rep(0.1, 25)

while(!converged & i <=25) {
  glm.out = glm(cbind(Menarche, Total-Menarche) ~ Age,
                mustart = mu,
                family=binomial(logit), data=menarche, 
                control=glm.control(maxit=1))
  mu <- glm.out$fitted.values
  coeftrace[i,] <- coef(glm.out)
  i <- i+1
  converged<- glm.out$converged
}

           [,1]      [,2]
 [1,] -18.18140 1.5441246
 [2,] -10.04138 0.6936207
 [3,] -11.95066 0.9018941
 [4,] -16.27171 1.2450011
 [5,] -19.71743 1.5147288
 [6,] -21.07972 1.6206137
 [7,] -21.22499 1.6318598
 [8,] -21.22639 1.6319683
 [9,] -21.22639 1.6319683
[10,]   0.00000 0.0000000
[11,]   0.00000 0.0000000
```